# Future warning - indexing with a float is deprecated - having trouble finding another solution

Tags: pandas

I'm getting the following warning when running the below code:

if df.loc[df.index[i-1],'column'] == 1:

FutureWarning: Indexing with a float is deprecated, and will raise an IndexError in pandas 2.0. You can manually convert to an integer key instead.

How can I rewrite this to avoid the warning?

Comment: Are you sure the data type needs to be float? That's a strange one because float values can be so varied and unqiue that it doesn't seem likst a good candidate for indexing.

Comment: If you want to get a value by its row number, perhaps you should use `df.iloc[]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For temporary purposes, you can use,

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
```